# How can I use Photoshop's filter to remove motion blur without getting a doubled-image effect?

Tags: photoshop, motion-blur

Recently I've been playing with Photoshop with this picture. What I did is that I removed the motion blur using the Filters and now the picture looks like there are 2 same pictures overlapping. Here's the picture: [image: Àter editing]
And the original one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0EMn.jpg

Comment: Thelink above is to an image which has two overlapping exposures in it - is that the result AFTER deblurring? If so, can you post the original before deblurring. mIf the link IS to a pre deblurring version then there are two distinct images there.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Nope. No deblurring. It's completely original. Weird, huh?

Comment: This can happen for several reasons. (1) THere really were two images - a possibility here as the effect is FAR less obvious further down and may be due there to other factors. (2) Flash and background lighting give different images - if the camera was stationary over much of the exposure but moving or had moved when the flash fired you may get two exposures. This is especially common when flash is used but background light can supply much of the exposure. If there is a "party strobe" working this can contribute.  {3) Similar to 2. but STiLL-move-STILL exposure..... -> contd ...

Comment: ....  (4) If the backdrop is over another surface with a small gap between the two you may get shadow and/or projection of the front layer on the rear. || Examination of the majority of the image suggests that the effect is pronounced with the top text and much less so for the poeple. With the people it is far harder to tell due to shape/contrast/edges etc. | How does the rest of the image seen when "sharpened".

Comment: @RussellMcMahon By sharpened you mean the tiny image in the question?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question. IF the large image is the unprocessed original and the small image is sharpened outp[ut then the result is unsurprising as the double effect is in the large image, which I understand you to say is the original. || My question was: If the large image is the original, when you sharpen the whole image, do you get a multiple image anywhere except in the "text" at the top? If so, can you give an example?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The small image is just a piece of it. You can try reducing motion blur yourself in Photoshop.

Comment: I see both motion and strobe effects in the main image. Motion blur is largely horizontal and is smooth and is fairly similar everywhere on the image. There is also some strobe effect. from different illuminants. This can come from the way lights are wired and may sync with the AC lines. Some of the image is lit with constant light and some with light that is pulsing. The latter creates stronger exposures separated by the motion effect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the double-text effect is because of blur removal, but strobing lightning on the background. I don't have Photoshop, but using SmartDeblur 1.27, the double-text effect diminished a lot: 
[image: OP's image adjusted in SmartDeblur for the Merry Christmas text]
I'm hoping that Photoshop would be even better. Also the later, paid version of SmartDeblur seems to be more advanced. (This image is corrected for the Christmas text, other parts would look a bit better with other settings.)

The OP's filtered crop is so small that it's difficult to say, but it seems that it's not using enough correction. Maybe the Photoshop automation is looking at the sharper looking details from the strobing lights in the Christmas tree? According to the [Adobe documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/reduce-camera-shake-induced-blurring.html) there is an "Advanced panel" that should have the tools to adjust the amount and direction of motion.

It seems that the image could be enhanced with good tools, but the Christmas tree might look better uncorrected, as the strobing point lights will create funny effects.

Answer (score 0):

I used to fix using **Shake Reduction Filter** under **Filter -> Sharpen menu**.
This filter is available in Photoshop CC, not sure if it is available in other versions.

You should use it effectively to succeed.